# Is there a way to make the ternary operator work for Cloud Firestore Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In our Firebase setup we store the user's role in custom claims. And so, in our Cloud Firestore security rules we need to evaluate whether the user has the appropriate role to perform an action. So I created the function `getRole` which conveniently gets the requested value from the user's auth token. However, there are certain edge cases when the user does not yet have a role, and in those cases I want their role to evaluate to the lowest possible security role, in our case this is just `"user"`. I read the language spec for CEL (Common Expression Language) which is what this rule language is based on and it does in fact support a ternary operator. ([Doc](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md)). So I went and plugged in this code into my Firestore security rules and the online editor validated the rules and accepted my new rules. However, I later found that locally, when running my security rules unit tests and also loading up the rules in the firebase emulators, I get this error:

`ERROR Use of ternary operator not allowed`

So either the production Firestore rules support the ternary operator and the local emulators do not, or the production one is validating against CEL and passing validation when they should not.

At any rate, I would like to safely be able to have a function which returns the actual value of the user's role, or a default safe value if it is not set.

Please note that we have tried to omit the `'role' in getCustomClaims()` statement and it blows up if the key does not exist in the custom claims.

```
function getCustomClaims() {
  return request.auth.token;
}
function getRole() {
  return 'role' in getCustomClaims() ? getCustomClaims()['role'] : 'user';
}
```

Comment: For security rules, the local emulator should be exactly the same as what's in the cloud service, but if it's not, you should file an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub with the steps to reproduce. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: I have the same issue, the emulator wont accept my security rules because of the ternary operator. Have you filed the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make this work without a ternary operator.  You can see that, from the [rules API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth), that `request.auth.token` is a map type object.  The API docs for [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) says that there is a method called [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#get) which accepts a default ("safe") value to return if the passed key isn't found:

```
getCustomClaims().get("role", "user")
```

Comment: This is the correct way of doing this. However, The ternary operator was recently introduced and is now available for use FYI. (it wasn't when this question was asked).

Comment: @ScottCrossen, do you get the ternary operator to work in the emulator?

Comment: @Oliver Thanks for catching this! I've added the ternary operator to be released with the next version of the emulator.

Comment: Thanks  @ScottCrossen for adding ?: op. Is it documented anywhere?
I'll be adding it to my quick reference at:
  https://github.com/tohagan/firestore-quickreference

Comment: Yep! It's documented as an "operator" on this page

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#building_conditions

But it's also in the release notes for rules

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020